# Nested categories in the x-axis of an already facetted plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this code

```
data <- data.frame(Var = as.factor(rep(c("A", "B", "C"),4)),
               Treatment = as.factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3),rep(4,3))),
               Value = runif(12,0,1),
               Group = as.factor(c(rep("X",6), rep("Y",6))))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(Var, Value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill= Var), stat = "identity", position = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~Group)
```

As you can see, ggplot only plots the first value of Var, as factor "Treatment" is not defined in the plot command, thus unknown.

I want to have the "var"-category nested by "Treatment" of the x-axis in each facet.

Similar questions have been posted already, but i could not find an exact duplicate.

/edit:
The plot should look like this (but without the redundant legends):

```
list2env(split.data.frame(data, data$Group), .GlobalEnv )

p1 <- ggplot(X, aes(Var, Value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill= Treatment), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") 
p2 <- ggplot(Y, aes(Var, Value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill= Treatment), stat = "identity", position = "dodge")

library(cowplot)

plot_grid(p1, p2, align="hv")
```

Comment: How many plots are you hoping to have by the end?

Comment: just 4. I have thought about splitting 'data' by `Group` and make 4 different single plots.

Comment: By saying the legends are redundant, it makes me think your treatment factor levels of 3 and 4 are equal to 1 and 2, respectively, and should be changed. You can then rerun your initial `ggplot` function and change the `fill` argument to `Treatment` (also specify `position="dodge"`). Such a process produces the plots you highlight in your post.

Comment: Yup. The position = "dodge" argument i missed entirely. But the treatment factors are actually not redundant.Thank you!